# How many points distant from each other can fall in a ball?

Tags: geometry

Let's say we have a closed ball  $B(x,r)\subset\mathcal{R}^n$ centered at $x$ with radius $r$.

The question I want to ask is: how many distinct points in $\mathcal{R}^n$, in which the distance between any two points is larger than or equal to $r$, can fall in $B(x,r)$?

When $n=2$, the question is easy to visualise. But to imagine the case generally when $n$ is large is not so easy.

I think the points must be located on the boundary of $B(x,r)$ to maximise the number. Therefore it is possible to derive an upper bound by estimating the area each point would occupy on the boundary of $B(x,r)$. But the computation gets complicated because the area occupied by several points depends on the location of these points.

Thanks!

Comment: If $x=0$ and $r=1$ and you say "larger than or equal to" instead of "larger than" then I think your question is equivalent to "how many balls of radius $1/2$ can fit into a ball of radius $3/2$".

Comment: @KeithMcClary Thank you for your hint. Based on your hint, I estimated that the maximum number in 2 dimension is 7, and 14 in 3 dimension. But I still can't imagine higher-dimensional spaces. Is there a general solution to this?

Comment: I don't know much about this, except that it is unintuitive, [for example in a unit cube of 9 or more dimensions you can fit an extra ball of diameter $1/2$ in the middle](https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2007/07/21/spheres-in-higher-dimensions/). I found the Question ["Sphere packing question AGAIN"](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2009321/252672) which has some "Related" questions.